# remove white space and empty search using ajax and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am facing problem when i give only the space i got results from the database using jQuery Ajax function, when i give space and remove the space i return all results from the database please help how to fix this.
here is my html

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" id="search" data-action="<?php echo site_url('home/search') ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for lectures">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default "  type="button">Go!</button>
              </span>
            </div><!-- /input-group -->         

        <div id="user_serach"></div>
        </div>
```

here is my jquery code

```
  $('#search').keyup(function(){
        var user_search  =  $('#search').val();
            if(user_search == ''){
                    $('#user_serach').text('');
            }
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).data('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        user_search:user_search
                    },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                            $('#user_serach').html(data).css('display','block');
                    },
                    error:function()
                    {
                        $('#user_serach').text('Some thing wrong..').css('color','red');
                    }
                });//ajax ends here

//search key up ends here
    });
```

here is my controller

```
public function search()
{
     $data['video_name'] = $this->input->post('user_search',TRUE);
     $data['search'] = $this->mod_home->get_search($data);
     if ($data['search']->num_rows() > 0 )
     {
         echo $this->load->view('home/search',$data);
     }

}
```

here is my model

```
public function get_search($data)
{
    return $this->db->select('*')->from('videos')->like('video_name',$data['video_name'])->get();
}
```

and here is my view

```
<div class="search_div">
    <?php foreach($search->result() as $row): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('videosd/video')?>?shakzee=<?php echo $row->video_id?>&id=<?php echo $row->course_id?>">
    <div><?php echo $row->video_name ?></div></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what space r u talking about? can u be a little specific pls?

Comment: if put nothing and only press the space button i got results from the database

Comment: if i write something to search and then i remove all characters from search bar but now characters is zero but still got all results from database

Answer (score 0):

Just trim the result before sending it to the controller

you can use jquery's **$.trim()** function if you want to remove the space.
I guess this is what you want
    var user_search  =  $.trim($('#search').val());

After the select query, run the following and check if this is the query you needed.

```
print_r($this->db->last_query());
```

LIKE '%%' matches any given string, even ones with zero ength. thats why you are getting all results from database

All you need to do is a simple validation

```
<input type="text" id="search" data-action="<?php echo site_url('home/search') ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for lectures" required>
```

use the html5 required **attribute** which will make the user to definitely submit the form with a text

From backend you can use **validation** class of codeigniter to check if the value is empty and then you can throw an error without executing a query

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: i tried but i don't know why its not working.! and also when i write something to search and i remove all characters form the search but still got all results from the database

Comment: here is last query SELECT * FROM (`videos`) WHERE `video_name` LIKE '%%'

Comment: see..this is the problem you are not specifying anything. there should be some data between % your search text %

Comment: when i write jquery so last query generate  SELECT * FROM (`videos`) WHERE `video_name` LIKE '%jquery%'

Comment: first of all you dont have to use $data variable for sending the data to the controller...it is used mailny for views. use a simple variable for ex: $searchtext = $this->input->post('user_search',TRUE); and pass this to controller

Comment: so ..it is functioning properly..is you write something, text is getting inserted in the query and if you dont, no text will be inserted so the database will return all the results

Comment: when i write i get exact results but when when i don't write and press the space button i get all results from database if press single character and then i remove that single character so also get all result form the database  :( please hlep

Comment: use  a simple validation...thats it. everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you

```
public function get_search($data)
    {
        if(strlen(trim($data['video_name']))>0)
        {
            return $this->db->select('*')->from('videos')->like('video_name',$data['video_name'])->get();    
        }
        else
        {
            return array();/basically it should be return null;but null will produce your view script error.
        }

    }
```